# OpenGL: GL_REPEAT and GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE

Tags: opengl

Im working on my game project with OGL 3.2 and I was using `GL_REPEAT` in the texture parameters to set up my terrain very fast by defining ST coordinates more than (1;1). But now, when I've added a skybox, an edges between skybox textures looks very scratchy and I don't want them to be. I can remove them by using `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` parameter, but terrain texture renders wrong without `GL_REPEAT` parameter. So I must choose between `GL_REPEAT` and `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. If I switch it to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` I can't use `GL_REPEAT` advantage and have to divide my terrain to smaller chunks and give texture to each one by one, which is (in my opinion) very inefficient, especially when I want huge sized map.

Is there any way to use both advantages of `GL_REPEAT` and `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` or maybe there is some more awesome way to solve this which I don't know?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use both at once.  The texture wrapping mode is stored on a per-texture basis, so use `GL_REPEAT` for your ground texture and `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` for your sky texture.

Set it for each texture immediately after (or immediately before, just as long as the texture is bound) uploading the texture image.